# Self-referencing relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, self-reference

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 code first and I have two entities and one abstract class that both entities inherits from.

```
public abstract class Customer
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public int FinancialStatusValue { get; internal set; }
}

public class Organization : Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string LegalName { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Vat { get; set; }
    public string Duns { get; set; }
    public Organization HeadQuarter { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> ChildOrganizations { get; set; }
}
```

I map my model with:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().ToTable("Organization");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasOptional(h => h.HeadQuarter)
            .WithMany(c => c.ChildOrganizations)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ParentId);

 }
```

I then query organization using:

```
var org = ctx.Customers.OfType<Organization>().Single(c => c.CustomerId == 259033);
```

ParentId is populated but HeadQuarter and ChildOrganizations are always null.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eager load the navigation properties by using `Include`:

```
var org = ctx.Customers.OfType<Organization>()
    .Include(o => o.HeadQuarter)
    .Include(o => o.ChildOrganizations)
    .Single(c => c.CustomerId == 259033);
```

You can also leverage lazy loading which would load the navigation properties when you access it the first time. You have to declare your navigation properties as `virtual`. (You did this only for `ChildOrganizations` but not for `HeadQuarter`.)

Be aware that `Include` will only load the navigation properties you exactly specify. It will not load your whole tree structure, i.e. not load `Organization.ChildOrganizations.ChildOrganizations`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does this work if I use ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>?

Comment: @RobinHu: I have no clue. Ask this better as a separate question ("How to eager load with SqlQuery?" or something). I have a little doubt though that it's possible at all because I believe that the column names which are returned by `SqlQuery` must be the same as the property names of the type `T` - and property names of related entities are not property names on `T`. So, basically `SqlQuery` can only populate scalar properties but not navigation properties. But sure I am not.